# extract distinct member names with their count

Tags: mysql

I need to extract distinct member names with their count of referrals they have produced. Below is my table. I am using MySQL

```
Mmeber_ID----MemberName------ReferralTo---
---  1  --------  Mike -------- Mitchell ------
---  2  --------  Mike ---------Jack ----
---  3  --------  Jill -------- Ricky ------
---  4  --------  John -------- Scott ------
```

The output i am looking for is as under;

```
MemberName------ReferralCount---
Mike -------- 2 ------
Jill -------- 1 ------
John -------- 1 ------
```

I have tried the following but i can't seem to find the solution passed it.
Any help will be appreciated;

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MemberName), COUNT(MemberName)
AS member 
FROM responses
WHERE MemberName='Mike'
```

Which only gives me Mike's result with its count. How can i get the results of the entire member's list?
Should this be solved using a nested query?

Comment: Simply add a `GROUP BY MemberName` to the end of your query. And remove the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Should `Mmeber_ID` not be unique? It seems odd that you would have a member with multiple ids. Perhaps that should be a `Referral_ID` instead.

Comment: Okay, Thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for grouping. Try the following query:

```
SELECT MemberName, Count(MemberName) as ReferralCount
FROM responses
GROUP BY MemberName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `COUNT` and similar aggregate functions, you must indicate a grouping. In this case, you want the count for each MemberName, so you must add the line: `GROUP BY MemberName`.

The query, then, is:

```
SELECT MemberName, COUNT(ReferralTo) as ReferralCount
FROM responses
GROUP BY MemberName
```